# Plupload jQuery UI widget and refreshing the queue

Tags: jquery, plupload

Alright I've been creating some test code to try and clear the upload queue, but I just don't know how to access the refresh() function from where I am. I'm using the jQuery UI widget as base to work from.
The part where I use INIT is giving me hell, I just can't seem to figure out how to refresh() from within my json call. I hope you can enlighten me as apparently I suck at jQuery.

```
    var do_continue = false;

    $("#uploader").plupload({
    // General settings
    runtimes : 'html5,browserplus,silverlight,gears,html4',
    url : CI.base_url + 'private/ad/upload_ad_images',
    max_file_size : '2mb',
    max_file_count: 5, // user can add no more then 20 files at a time
    //chunk_size : '1mb',
    unique_names : true,
    multiple_queues : true,

    // Resize images on clientside if we can
    //resize : {width : 800, height : 600, quality : 90},

    // Rename files by clicking on their titles
    rename: true,

    // Sort files
    sortable: true,

    // Specify what files to browse for
    filters : [
        {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"}
    ],

    // Flash settings
    flash_swf_url : CI.base_url + 'scripts/plupload/js/plupload.flash.swf',

    // Silverlight settings
    silverlight_xap_url : CI.base_url + 'scripts/plupload/js/plupload.silverlight.xap',
    // Post init events, bound after the internal events
    init : {
        QueueChanged: function(up) {
            // check for max photos here
            $.getJSON(CI.base_url + 'private/ad_ajax/count_uploaded_images/', function(data) {
            if (!data.message) {
                alert("no data found? - please contact us with this message.");
                do_continue = false;
            }else if(data.message != "go") {
                alert("Maximum photo uploads reached.");
                do_continue = false;
            }
            if (!do_continue) {
                $(this).refresh(); // -->> need something that works here
            }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.getJSON(CI.base_url + 'private/ad_ajax/count_uploaded_images/', function(data) {
if(data.message != "go") {
    alert("Maximum photo uploads reached.");
    do_continue = false;
    plupload.each(files, function(file) {
        up.removeFile(file);
    });
}
});
```

Was the answer - up.refresh() etc did not work for some reason.

Comment: `uploader.splice();`  is enough to clear the queue.. maybe using jquery.ui, or flash plugin you will need the refresh afterwards

Answer (score 3):

What exactly are you trying to refresh within the UI? As far as I know refresh() only redraws the plupload transparent shim for the runtimes in the correct position. It does not reload the entire UI or refresh/clear the upload queue.

If you could elaborate a bit more as to what/why you are trying a refresh I may be able to help you further. Either way, refresh based on your code is called as follows:

```
up.refresh();
```

If you are trying to empty the upload queue entirely that is done as follows:

```
up.splice();
```

or from anywhere else within your code using:

```
var uploader = $('#uploader').plupload('getUploader');
uploader.splice();
```

You may also want to check into the other available [events](http://www.plupload.com/example_events.php) as I suspect you should be doing your check on FilesAdded rather than on QueueChanged but depends what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Well, $(this).refresh() seems to refresh the upload queue when I put it directly in QueueChanged: function(up) {$(this).refresh()}. I want it to refresh only when the maximum amount of photos is reached which I'm pulling via $.getJSON. But (this) is not accessible within the getJSON function. I just need to know how to access the refresh/splice from within the getJSON function.